# Sharing folders in VMware similar to VirtualBox Shared Folders

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Basically, running into issues related to Docker volumes using WSL to communicate with Docker server in a VMware box. Docker runs fine with this setup until it comes to volumes, then no matter what I try I run into this error:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app 5932996c40dc

or

docker-compose up

npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T23_04_17_890Z-debug.log
```

I actually have a question about it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451141/npm-err-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-app-package-json

The [offered solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54682817/3123109) (using VirtualBox), was to do the following:

[image]

I'm trying to do something similar with VMware since I'd prefer to use it. I have other VMs besides this Docker one, and (to me) the performance is noticeably better than VirtualBox. Anyway, I'm trying to do something similar in VMware by doing the following:

[image]

Still running into the same issue though. The path that is referenced is where the project is located. The issues does not occur in Ubuntu, macOS, or using Hyper-V. Just this setup.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Also here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    command: ["npm", "run", "test"]
```

And here is the `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
FROM node:11.7.0-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: You are using bind-mounts and not Docker volumes. I would check out Docker volumes.

Comment: Try to user [docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases) in Windows. If same issue occurs then check your docker installation, the problem isn't in WSL.